# Why YouTube API doesn't work in 5.0 and later versions?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I use the YouTube API in Android and my Android Version is 4.4.4 and works perfect, but the same app in the (5.0/6.0/6.1/7.0/7.1) Android Versions don't work.

I don't know if this API works in newest Android versions.

Gradle Module: `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

[Project Distribution Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li1LX.png)

The version of Youtube Api is 1.2.2.

### Update

When the app run in the device with 5.0 or more Android Version get this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
                                             at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1219)
                                             at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1318)
                                             at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1296)
                                             at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:614)
                                             at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment.a(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                             at breaktherules.dherediat97.musiclegends.vista.JugarConInstrumentosActivity.onCreate(JugarConInstrumentosActivity.java:94)
                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

**`breaktherules.dherediat97.musiclegends.vista.JugarConInstrumentosActivity.onCreate(JugarConInstrumentosActivity.java:94)`**

And this it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
many code
...
    playerFragment.initialize(Constantes.YoutubeDeveloperKey, this);

}
```

This class is it:

```
public class JugarConInstrumentosActivity extends YoutubeFailureRecovery implements YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener {
```

Comment: As per the documentation **Note: Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.** Check the mobile youtube app version in your devices. is it up-to-date?

Comment: 4.4.4 smartphone youtube version is 12.16.56 and 6.0 smarthpone youtube version is the 12.16.56 the same...

Comment: hey, you are not using this api as a dependency in gradle file, right? only from libs folder, right?

Comment: yes, i only import in libs folder

Comment: can you show me your code according to this log entry only?

Comment: hey, there i found a work-around, not the optimum solution but you can give it a try. i guess you are using targetSdkVersion 25. do it 19 and it will work. don't know why is this working, i think there's some issue with the api itself.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes i update the question with more information

Comment: ok i try this right now and thanks :D

Comment: glad to help you and let me know if it's working. cheers!!

Comment: yes work perfectly is something strange :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Android SDK Version 25 to 19.

Comment: Solved and thanks you,what do i  when the question is solved?

Comment: @dherediat: you can click the tick mark adjacent to this answer to mark it as done. Alternatively, if you want the possibility of getting votes (up or down!) on the answer, copy it to a new one and I will delete my version. It is worth noting though that we prefer answers to be more substantial if possible. A good answer could explain the consequences of downgrading the SDK version, for example.